# ZF2: Zend framework 2.2 Controller not found error

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to create new module in Zend Skeleton applictaion. I am following the Zend framework's getting started tutorial about Album module. Only difference is I am using Project name instead of Album. Here is my module structure.

[image: module directory structure]

The contents of `module.config.php` is as below.

```
<?php
namespace Project;

return array(
  'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'project' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/project[/:action][/:id]',
                'contraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]+'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => __NAMESPACE__.'/Controller/'.__NAMESPACE__,
                    'action' => 'index'
                )
            )
        )
    )
  ),
  'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Project/Controller/Project' => 'Project/Controller/ProjectController',
    )
  ),
  'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'project' => __DIR__ . '../view',
    )
  ),
);
```

Contents of `Module.php` is as below.

```
<?php
namespace Project;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

The file `autoload_classmap.php` return only an empty array.

```
<?php
return array()
```

When I am trying to access the url `http://local.zf2/project/`, I get following error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Project/Controller/ProjectController' not found in 
/home/bliss/public_html/local.zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library
/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170
```

When I looked at the `AbstractPluginManager.php` file the line 170 contains `$instance = new $invokable();`.

I dumped `$invokable` variable to see the value it has. It returned `string(36) "Project/Controller/ProjectController"`

Somehow ZF2 is not able to find that file. Can some one please help? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the contents of `ProjectController.php` file. If it could find the file, it will die, showing the name of the file.

```
<?php
namespace Project\Controller;

die(__FILE__);

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class ProjectController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
//        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Seems like it detected the file but didnt found the right class in it. Check that class name and namespace are correct.

Comment: Updated question with contents of `ProjectController`

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong slashes in the defaults & invokables keys in module.config.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'controllers' => array(
  'invokables' => array(
      'Project/Controller/Project' => 'Project/Controller/ProjectController',
  )
),
```

You need to use backslashes on that one !
All the namespaces are declared with backslashes. That's probably why the AbstractPluginManager doesn't find your ProjectController ;).

```
'defaults' => array(
 'controller' => __NAMESPACE__.'/Controller/'.__NAMESPACE__,
'action' => 'index'
)
```

Same here

Comment: Yes, I also think it might be the problem. I'll check it tonight.

Comment: @Tounu What backslashes? I'm a bit confused -> your example doesn't seem to use backslashes?

Comment: @traditional Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm having exactly the same problem...

Comment: @Dannyboy Because this is not an example :p. You have to use backslashes in the code I quoted.

Comment: Ok - in my case error was the same, but it turned out to be not backslashes. I've digged all over internets trying to find an answer to no avail, but then accidentally noticed that module's code folder permissions show up as '????? ?? ??' in terminal. Since I'm using vagrant for development I've just did 'vagrant destroy;vagrant up' -> and code folder got mounted correctly. stupid stupid shit.

Answer (score 0):

Check your:

ProjectController.php

//must declare the class like below

```
class ProjectController extends AbstractActionController
```